# How to get text from a webpage outside my server through php?

Tags: php, text

I first send a term to a webpage outside my site. Then that page returns only text. I want to take that text and process it? So I'll have to get that text on my server for that right?
So how can i do it? or is there any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl) or [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) if your server has the [URL wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled.

Comment: hey thanks a lot Peter. The file_get_contents() function worked... its awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to read remote file using PHP

```
if ($fp = fopen('http://www.google.com/', 'r')) {
   $content = '';
   while ($line = fread($fp, 1024)) {
      $content .= $line;
   }
} else {
   // an error occured when trying to open the specified url 
}
```

Make sure you have 'allow_url_fopen' set to 1 in your php.ini